# Add the columns automatically in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

Currently we are having 6 columns in our database table which we are showing in the SSRS report but in future if we add 1 more column then without any manual changes on RDL it will included in the report.

Current report Example :-

```
Name    Address Code    City    County  Country
xyz     Lane 1  466001  Bang    dbc      Africa
abc     Lane 2  466002  Bpl     bbn      Nepal
dcb     Lane 3  466003  sbc     wad      Bhutan
```

Expected report without adding the column manually in SSRS.

```
Name    Address Code    City    County  Country DOB
xyz     Lane 1  466001  Bang    dbc     Africa  19/06/1986
abc     Lane 2  466002  Bpl     bbn     Nepal   20/06/1990
dcb     Lane 3  466003  sbc     wad     Bhutan  21/8/2000
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So how is the report expected to magically know your desired display format for date of birth? It would probably be possible by dynamically creating an UNPIVOT statement then using the column names as column groups but not sure it would be something I would do.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Check out my comment on Naveen's answer below, which would solve the formatting issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow below steps..

Step 1. Create Proc using UNPIVOT and Property(ColunName) & Value with ID column (PKey) like

```
SELECT Pkey,tblPivot.Property, tblPivot.Value
 FROM (SELECT EmpNo AS Pkey, CONVERT(sql_variant,EmpNo) AS EmpNo, CONVERT(sql_variant,EName) AS EName, CONVERT(sql_variant,JOB) AS JOB, 
 CONVERT(sql_variant,Sal) AS Sal FROM EMP) EMP 
UNPIVOT (Value For Property In (EmpNo,EName, JOB, Sal)) as tblPivot
```

Step 2.

Create a Matrix Report using above SP with row-grouping on [Pkey] and col-grouping on [Property] and Display value ...

[image]

Step 3 Now you can add/remove column in SP (step 1) based on your requirement

Comment: +1. Adding to this, and to answer Martin Smith's question in the comment above, you could control formatting of newly added columns, by creating a table to hold format strings for properties added in the future. This table should contain two columns: Property and FormatString. Using the SSRS-function LOOKUP() in the Format expression of the Tablix-cell in which the value is shown, you could then format the newly added column any way you desire.

Comment: Thanks Naveen and Dan.+1 for both of you.

Comment: my columns are dynamic in nature and column header changes and data also changes? how to incorporate that?