# Display ssrs report data vertically in columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am struggling with a simple data arrangement issue.

I have 2 columns of data - location and area.
By default data is displayed as following:

```
Area1 Location1
Area1 Location2
Area2 Location3
Area3 Location4
```

I would like to display data as follows:

```
Area1      Area2      Area3
Location1  Location3  Location4
Location2
```

Sorry about formatting, I hope it makes sense.
Thank you

Edit
This is the actual query that I used to get the data:

```
select a.location_area_code, l.location_code
from stock_location_level as l
    inner join stock_location as a
    on l.location_code = a.location_code
where l.branch_number = '99' and a.suspended = 'N'
group by a.location_area_code, l.location_code
having SUM(l.physical_quantity) = 0
Order by a.location_area_code, l.location_code
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example is that the only thing location 1 has in common with location 3 and 4 is that they are the first location in their respective area.

add this to your dataset.

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [area] ORDER BY [Location]) as row_num
```

then create a matrix row grouped on the new row_num field and column grouped on area field.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Matrix.. you already have Data in desired format like Areay & Location..
You just need to do column grouping on Area and set display value as Location.

For more details please refer to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240227/3198474)

Comment: I tried using matrix by putting location_area_code in columns and a) location_code in rows getting all the locations listed in the left column; b) location_code in data getting only 1 location per area.