# SSRS How to "Unpivot" my pivotted table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS sub report that is dynamically retrieving from different tables based on auctioning different cells. In order to do this, I pivot the tables at the sql server end using dynamic sql in a procedure.

When it gets into SSRS it obviously looks like this.

```
Field    Value
Product Dining Table
Length  1.2m
Width   1m
Height  0.9m
Colour  Brown
Product Bench
Length  2m
Width   .4m
Height  0.6m
Colour  White
```

Is there a clever way to "unpivot" the table in SSRS so that I get it like so.

```
Product         Length  Width   Height  Colour
Dining Table    1.2m    1m  0.9m    Brown
Bench           2m  .4m 0.6m    White
```

I've tried using a matrix but I can't figure out a way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at the matrix guide? It takes you step-by-step in SRSS.

Comment: Why not unpivot it in the SQL?

Comment: If I unpivot it in SQL then I can't dynamically retrieve multiple tables using the same sub report in SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here only thing missing is to get unique ID along with SQL result set, then that field is used in Row Grouping. 
You can refer to similar post [Add the columns automatically in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240227/3198474) posted by me

Comment: I did try this approach but I couldn't figure out a way to add a unique ID to the sql set to get this approach to work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Okay, your work helped me figure out what I needed to do. Thank you!