# SQL Server Merging help needed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I can't work out how to do this:

```
Surname Firstname EmpID ListName 
--------------------------------
Smith   john      123   list1
Smith   john      123   list2
Jones   James     124   list1
```

I need

```
Surname Firstname EmpID ListName1  ListName2 
--------------------------------------------
Smith   john      123   list1      List 2
Jones   James     124   list1      *null*
```

Comment: Do a [DISTINCT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm) on the `EmpID`.

Comment: Have you tried the UNPIVOT approach as shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24240227/2311633?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a number for the rows, with something like this:

```
select row_number() over (partition by Surname Firstname EmpID order by ListName) as RN, ...
```

And then use that row number for deciding what data to show where with something like:

```
select Surname Firstname EmpID,
  max(case when RN = 1 then ListName end) as ListName1,
  max(case when RN = 2 then ListName end) as ListName2
from (
```